# How to disappear the browser's scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to hide the browser's horizontal and vertical scroll through HTML or Javascript?
I have a listing and for that I have made my own div to div scroller  and I want to hide the browser's scroll bars
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe, but you *really* shouldn't be reinventing the scroll bar. Many users do not appreciate this.

Comment: i am not reinventing it, i have just made an image that gives an affect of scrolling

Comment: So, what you want is to style the scrollbars with your own design? Or delete them completely for other purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `overflow: hidden` to `html` and/or `body` in CSS but then, of course, you have to be careful so that your `<div>` doesn't expand past the browser window.

Example:

```
html, body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the body tag to `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the css for the div to hide the scrollbar. Put everything into a main div and set the css for the main div to this:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
```

then use your own scrollbars on the content div.