# Hide browser scroll-bars

Tags: html, css, iscroll

I'm using the plugin iscroll just in my `data-role="content"` but there's a huge scrollbar appearing in my full page:
[scrollbar](http://prntscr.com/7acybx)

I already tried some solutions found here in SO like:

1. [pilsetnieks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282153/how-to-disappear-the-browsers-scroll-bar)
2. [Alexander Prokofyev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars)
3. [jao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296644/hiding-the-scrollbar-on-an-html-page)
4. [Mr_Green's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)

but none work.

I check this [website](https://coderwall.com/p/4wa6ba/hide-browser-scroll-bars) too, but no luck either.

Can you help me?

My **HTML**:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
            <div id="Container"></div>
            <div id="Treelist">
                <div id="scroller">
                    <ul id="Listview" ></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My **CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

#Treelist {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* Prevent native touch events on Windows */
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    /* Prevent the callout on tap-hold and text selection */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    /* Prevent text resize on orientation change, useful for web-apps */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
    -o-text-size-adjust: none;
    text-size-adjust: none;
}

#scroller {
    position:relative; z-index:1;
/* Prevent elements to be highlighted on tap */
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    /* Put the scroller into the HW Compositing layer right from the start */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}


#Treelist ul {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}

#Treelist li {
    padding:0 10px;
    height:150px;
/*  line-height:40px; */
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: You mean this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16670931/1577396)

Comment: On which browser do you have this problem?

Comment: @Mr_Green I'm using this [plugin](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/simple/)

Comment: @Mr_Green your answer did not work too. In fact, it made my `ul` disappear

Comment: Then it seems the problem is somewhere else. Please create a small fiddle which demonstrates your problem. If you do so we can help you further.

Comment: @Mr_Green just found the problem right now. It was a CSS I had there. I don't know why it gave me that scrollbar while in another project that CSS didn't show the scrollbar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use this in order to hide the scrollbars:

```
#scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}

#scroller {
-ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Just have a look at it in different browsers, I'm sure it works in Safari, IE and Chrome

Comment: The scrollbar persists :(

Answer (score -1):

This should work in Webkit based browsers (Chrome/Safari) as well as IE 10+.

```
div::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important; display: none; }
div { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

Unfortunately, there is no good cross browser solutions to edit scrollbars. Scrollbars are created by the browser, and as such the amount that we can do to them is limited by what the browsers allow. I've learned it's best to just leave them alone, most people don't even notice them.

Comment: The scrollbar persists